# string cannot be cast to Accessibility delegate accessibility role

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am creating a button in react native using react native component Button. But I am getting an error on android that java.lang.String cannot be cast to Accessibility delegate accessibility role.

If I remove the button code the application runs fine. If I use the Touchable Opacity it also works fine then.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title={"Login"} onPress={() => alert("Hi")} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
});
```

My react native version is 0.57.3

What I have tried.

1. Adding accessibility text.
2. Using touchable opacity.
3. Btw I have seen a so question with answer saying to downgrade the react native version to 0.57.1 There should be a more simple solution than just downgrading the whole thing.

Comment: Facing the same issue while using Button. Till yesterday everything was fine. The react native decided to update automatically somehow and BOOOM!

Comment: This is a bug, reported to project : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21754 (but it seems that annoyed people were a bit harsh on FB.)